# Setting up vuejs and laravel

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I'm fairly new to Vue and only learn a little bit of it. Actually it's my first time seeing this beautiful library (whatever you may call it ) And i saw many developers actually pulling many dependencies from npm like vueify, and many more. Now, I just want to ask. I'm only a beginner. and what i know is to just pull of my files and store them in my resources/assets/js folder and just do elixir on them. And, is it really a good practice to just pull of those dependencies and browserify/webpack on them regardless the size of the app i'm developing ? Humbly asking for opinions

Comment: Leave them where they are and let NPM manage them. Given that you're new to it, trust the experts. There's a reason Laravel includes a starter implementation - to establish best practices.